# Volley JsonObjectRequest Recyclerview Adapter Inside OnResponse

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I have a database.(XAMMP)
I'am able to get all the values.
I'am using a recycler view and populate the recyclerview given the value from my database.
I have put the recyclerview adapter inside onresponse,
but the static value of textviews has gone. 
Is there a better way to populate the recyclerview(onBackground)?

```
public void getComments() {
        final List<Comments> commentsData = new ArrayList<>();
        Global.getCommentTitle.clear();
        Global.getCommentPicture.clear();
        Global.getComment.clear();
        Global.getCommentDate.clear();
        Global.getCommentRating.clear();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("poi");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Global.getCommentTitle.add(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        Global.getCommentPicture.add("drawable://" + R.drawable.juandirection_placeholder);
                        Global.getComment.add(jsonObject.getString("comment"));
                        Global.getCommentDate.add(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                        Global.getCommentRating.add(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("rating")));
                        if (i < 5) {
                            Comments current = new Comments();
                            current.image = "drawable://" + R.drawable.juandirection_placeholder;
                            current.title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                            current.comment = jsonObject.getString("comment");
                            current.date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                            current.rating = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("rating"));
                            commentsData.add(current);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        List<Information> headerData = new ArrayList<>();
                        int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_information, R.drawable.ic_place_black_36dp, R.drawable.ic_local_see_black_24dp};
                        for (int i = 0; i < Global.getHeader.size(); i++) {
                            Information headerInfo = new Information();
                            headerInfo.iconId = icons[i];
                            headerInfo.title = Global.getHeader.get(i);
                            headerData.add(headerInfo);
                        }

                        if (commentsData.size() == 5) {
                            Information current = new Information();
                            current.iconId = R.drawable.ic_comment_black_24dp;
                            current.title = "View more Comments";
                            headerData.add(current);
                        }
                        Log.e("SIZE", "" + commentsData.size());


                        List<Rating> ratingData = new ArrayList<>();
                        Rating ratingInfo = new Rating();
                        ratingInfo.reviewTxt = "Bulacan State University";
                        ratingData.add(ratingInfo);
                        ratingInfo.ratingBarReview = 2;
                        ratingData.add(ratingInfo);
                        ratingInfo.progressbarE = 20;
                        ratingData.add(ratingInfo);
                        ratingInfo.progressbarVG = 40;
                        ratingData.add(ratingInfo);
                        ratingInfo.progressbarAVG = 60;
                        ratingData.add(ratingInfo);
                        ratingInfo.progressbarP = 80;
                        ratingData.add(ratingInfo);
                        ratingInfo.progressbarT = 95;
                        ratingData.add(ratingInfo);


                        List<Header> headerData2 = new ArrayList<>();
                        String[] header = {"Information", "Photos", "Reviews"};
                        for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                            Header current = new Header();
                            current.header = header[i];
                            headerData2.add(current);
                        }

                        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvPOI);
                        adapter = new AdapterPOI(getApplicationContext(), headerData, headerData2, ratingData, commentsData);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext()));
                        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), mRecyclerView, new ClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                                if (position == 2) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewInformation.class));
                                }
                                if (position == 3) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                if (position == 6) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add Photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                if (position >= 9 && position <= 13) {
                                    Global.viewCommets = position - 9;
                                    Global.singleComment = true;
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewComment.class));
                                }
                                if (position == 14) {
                                    Global.singleComment = false;
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewComment.class));
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        VolleyHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Even the Recyclerview ripple effect has gone. 
What's seems to be the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="Bulacan State University"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBarReview"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar"
            android:rating="3.5"
            android:stepSize=".5"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Excelent"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Very Good"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Average"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Poor"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Terrible"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="14dp">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressbarE"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="9dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:maxHeight="10dip"
                    android:minHeight="10dip"
                    android:progress="90"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressbarVG"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="9dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:maxHeight="10dip"
                    android:minHeight="10dip"
                    android:progress="75"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressbarAVG"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="9dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:maxHeight="10dip"
                    android:minHeight="10dip"
                    android:progress="65"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar" />


                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressbarP"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="9dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:maxHeight="10dip"
                    android:minHeight="10dip"
                    android:progress="45"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressbarT"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="9dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:maxHeight="10dip"
                    android:minHeight="10dip"
                    android:progress="10"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

AdapterPOI..

```
public class AdapterPOI extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPOI.MainViewHolder> {
    List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();
    List<Header> headerData = Collections.emptyList();
    List<Rating> ratingsData = Collections.emptyList();
    List<Comments> commentsData = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    int viewType = 0;
    int headerCounter = 0;
    int vCounter = 0;
    int rCounter = 0;
    int cCounter = 0;
    int[] routeImg = {R.drawable.ic_resto_route, R.drawable.ic_sights_route, R.drawable.ic_transport_route, R.drawable.ic_hotel_route,
            R.drawable.ic_gas_route, R.drawable.ic_school_route, R.drawable.ic_entertainment_route,
            R.drawable.ic_shop_route, R.drawable.ic_atm_route, R.drawable.ic_bank_route, R.drawable.ic_hospital_route,
            R.drawable.ic_pharmacy_route, R.drawable.ic_police_route, R.drawable.ic_toilet_route,};

    public AdapterPOI(Context context, List<Information> data, List<Header> headerData, List<Rating> ratingsData, List<Comments> commentsData) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        this.headerData = headerData;
        this.context = context;
        this.ratingsData = ratingsData;
        this.commentsData = commentsData;
    }


    @Override
    public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        int listViewItemType = getItemViewType(viewType);
        Log.e("FUCK ME",""+commentsData.size());
        if(listViewItemType == 0 ){
            return new TitleHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_title, parent, false));
        }
        if (listViewItemType == 1 || listViewItemType == 4 || listViewItemType == 7) {
            return new HeaderHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.headerinformation, parent, false));
        }if (listViewItemType == 2 || listViewItemType == 6 || listViewItemType == 3 || listViewItemType == 14) {
            return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_pictext, parent, false));
        }if (listViewItemType == 5) {
            return new GalleryHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_photos, parent, false));
        }if (listViewItemType == 8) {
            return new RatingHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_rating, parent, false));
        }if (listViewItemType >= 9 && listViewItemType<=8+commentsData.size()) {
            return new CommentsHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_comments, parent, false));
        } if (listViewItemType >= 9+commentsData.size()) {
            return new TapHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_taptorate, parent, false));
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("TAE: ",""+Global.selectedPOI);
        if(position==0){

            TitleHolder mHolder = (TitleHolder) holder;
            mHolder.imgType.setBackgroundResource(routeImg[Global.getPosition]);
            mHolder.txtTitle.setText(Global.selectedPOI);
            //imgFavorite=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFavorite);
            //txtTitle=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            //ratingBar=(RatingBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        }

        if (position == 1 || position == 4 || position == 7) {
            if (position == 1) {
                headerCounter = 0;
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                headerCounter = 1;
            }
            if (position == 7) {
                headerCounter = 2;
            }
            Header current = headerData.get(headerCounter);
            HeaderHolder mHolder = (HeaderHolder) holder;
            mHolder.txtInfo.setText(current.header);
        }

        if (commentsData.size() == 5) {
            if (position == 14) {
                vCounter = 3;
                Information current = data.get(vCounter);
                MyViewHolder mHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                mHolder.title.setText(current.title);
                mHolder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
            }
        }

        if (position == 2 || position == 3 || position == 6) {
            if (position == 2) {
                vCounter = 0;
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                vCounter = 1;
            }
            if (position == 6) {
                vCounter = 2;
            }
            Information current = data.get(vCounter);
            MyViewHolder mHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            mHolder.title.setText(current.title);
            mHolder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);

        }
        if (position == 5) {
            GalleryHolder mHolder = (GalleryHolder) holder;
            GalleryViewAdapterPOI galleryViewAdapter;
            galleryViewAdapter = new GalleryViewAdapterPOI(context, Global.IMAGES);
            mHolder.gallery.setAdapter(galleryViewAdapter);
            final WindowManager display = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            display.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mHolder.gallery.getLayoutParams();
            mlp.setMargins(-((metrics.widthPixels * 2 + 200) / 3), mlp.topMargin,
                    mlp.rightMargin, mlp.bottomMargin);
        }
        if (position == 8) {
            Rating current = ratingsData.get(0);
            RatingHolder mHolder = (RatingHolder) holder;
            mHolder.reviewTxt.setText(current.reviewTxt);
            mHolder.ratingBarReview.setRating(current.ratingBarReview);
            mHolder.progressbarE.setProgress(current.progressbarE);
            mHolder.progressbarVG.setProgress(current.progressbarVG);
            mHolder.progressbarAVG.setProgress(current.progressbarAVG);
            mHolder.progressbarP.setProgress(current.progressbarP);
            mHolder.progressbarT.setProgress(current.progressbarT);
        }

        if (position >= 9 && position <= 8 + commentsData.size()) {
            if (position == 9) {
                cCounter = 0;
            }
            if (position == 10) {
                cCounter = 1;
            }
            if (position == 11) {
                cCounter = 2;
            }
            if (position == 12) {
                cCounter = 3;
            }
            if (position == 13) {
                cCounter = 4;
            }
            Comments current = commentsData.get(cCounter);
            CommentsHolder mHolder = (CommentsHolder) holder;
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(current.image)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.juandirection_placeholder)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .fit()
                    .into(mHolder.commentPhoto);
            mHolder.commentTitle.setText(current.title);
            mHolder.commentDate.setText(current.date);
            mHolder.comments.setText(current.comment);
            mHolder.commentRatingbar.setRating(current.rating);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size() + headerData.size() + commentsData.size() + 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (position == 0) {
            viewType = 0;
        } else if (position == 1) {
            viewType = 1;
        } else if (position == 2) {
            viewType = 2;
        } else if (position == 3) {
            viewType = 3;
        } else if (position == 4) {
            viewType = 4;
        } else if (position == 5) {
            viewType = 5;
        } else if (position == 6) {
            viewType = 6;
        } else if (position == 7) {
            viewType = 7;
        } else if (position == 8) {
            viewType = 8;
        } else if (position == 9) {
            viewType = 9;
        } else if (position == 10) {
            viewType = 10;
        } else if (position == 11) {
            viewType = 11;
        } else if (position == 12) {
            viewType = 12;
        } else if (position == 13) {
            viewType = 13;
        } else if (position == 14) {
            viewType = 14;
        }else if (position == 15) {
            viewType = 15;
        }


        return viewType;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends MainViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.poiName);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.poiIcon);

        }

    }


    public class HeaderHolder extends MainViewHolder {
        TextView txtInfo;

        public HeaderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.txtInfo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtinfo);

        }
    }

    public class GalleryHolder extends MainViewHolder {
        Gallery gallery;

        public GalleryHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.gallery = (Gallery) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gallery);

        }
    }

    public class TapHolder extends MainViewHolder {
        RatingBar ratingBar;

        public TapHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.ratingBar = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tapToRate);
            this.ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                    Global.setRating = rating;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,Review.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public class TitleHolder extends MainViewHolder {
        ImageView imgType,imgFavorite;
        TextView txtTitle;
        RatingBar ratingBar;

        public TitleHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgType=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgType);
            imgFavorite=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFavorite);
            txtTitle=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            ratingBar=(RatingBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        }
    }

    public class RatingHolder extends MainViewHolder {
        TextView reviewTxt;
        RatingBar ratingBarReview;
        ProgressBar progressbarE, progressbarVG, progressbarAVG, progressbarP, progressbarT;

        public RatingHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.reviewTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reviewTxt);
            this.ratingBarReview = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarReview);
            this.progressbarE = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressbarE);
            this.progressbarVG = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressbarVG);
            this.progressbarAVG = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressbarAVG);
            this.progressbarP = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressbarP);
            this.progressbarT = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressbarT);
        }
    }


    public class CommentsHolder extends MainViewHolder {
        ImageView commentPhoto;
        TextView commentTitle, commentDate, comments;
        RatingBar commentRatingbar;

        public CommentsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.commentPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentPhoto);
            this.commentTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentTitle);
            this.commentDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentDate);
            this.comments = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            this.commentRatingbar = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentRatingbar);
        }
    }

    public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public MainViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by but the static value of textviews has gone.

Comment: I mean, I already declare the value of the textviews from the XML file. it should be loaded just like normal. You can look in my XML. the Very Good, Excellent etc... that's gone when I run the program.

Comment: Plz provide AdapterPOI.

Comment: I have already provided the adapterPOI..

Comment: Can you log ratingsData  in if (position == 8) {
      }  and log text , textColor ,backgroundColor of mHolder.reviewTxt

Comment: 11-15 22:00:52.715 5774-5774/? E/Text: Bulacan State University
11-15 22:00:52.715 5774-5774/? E/Text Color: ColorStateList{mStateSpecs=[[]]mColors=[-16738680]mDefaultColor=-16738680}
11-15 22:00:52.715 5774-5774/? E/Background: null

Comment: The reviewTxtis workin fine.. the one is im having problem with is the TextViews that Contains Excellent, Very Good. The texts already define in XML. It should show when i Run the program. I don't know what it isn't

Comment: I think @string/Excelent . where is you Excelent?

Comment: one problem solved. I just put textcolor on the texts. sorry simple mistake.  
but still having a problem in recyclerview ripple effect.

Comment: What is recyclerview ripple effect?

Comment: Ripple Effect is when you press the recyclerview, the pressed one changed background/highlight

Comment: Do you even get it in other recyclerview?

Comment: nope. just this one..

Comment: i add a answer .  You should add background youself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom_row_rating.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_white_press"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```

btn_white_press.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#4b14b1"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks.. This works for me but i changed the Selector Tag on Ripple Tag. thankyou! :)

Comment: Do you mean <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
</ripple>.It requires Api21.

Comment: yes. in API 21 i use ripple. and in non api 21 i use selector.